# How to show that $f$ is not totally differentiable, using formal definition

Tags: derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

> Given that $$f(x,y)= \begin{cases}
>       \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}, & \text{if $(x,y)\neq0$}.\\
>       0, & \text{if $(x,y)=0$}   \end{cases}$$ I want to show that $f$ cannot be totally differentiable at $(0,0)$.

I can show that $f$ is not totally differentiable at $(0,0)$ by showing that it isnt continous at $(0,0)$, however I need to prove it using the definition of total differentiability, which says that some $f$ is totally differentiable at $x$ if there exists some $L$ such that $$f(x+\xi)=f(x)+L\xi+\varphi(\xi)$$ where $$\lim_{\xi \to 0} \frac{\varphi(\xi)}{\ \|\xi\|}=0$$
I am confused by the notation of this definition. Surely this definition should be based around the idea of differentiability at $(x,y)$, not just $x$?

Comment: On the second part: Here $x$ stands for an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$. In multiple variable analysis this notation is very common, and you should get used to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(cy,y)=\frac{cy^2}{cy^2+y^2}=\frac{c}{c+1}$$
So
$$\lim_{\xi\to 0}f(\xi)\neq 0$$

Now assume such an $L$ exists. Then:

$$||f(x+\xi)-f(x)||=||L\xi+\varphi(\xi)||\leq||L||\;||\xi||+||\varphi(\xi)||$$

Since $\lim_{\xi\to 0} \frac{||\varphi(\xi)||}{||\xi||}=0$ we find a $\delta>0$ such that for all $\xi\in B(0;\delta)$ we have $||\varphi(\xi)||/||\xi||\leq 1$. Now:
$$||\varphi(\xi)||\leq ||\xi||$$
Combining with the previous result we see:
$$||f(x+\xi)-f(x)||\leq(||L||+1)||\xi||$$
Hence $||f(x+\xi)-f(x)||\to 0 $ as $\xi\to 0$.

So we see that:
$$\lim_{\xi\to 0} f(\xi)= 0$$

Contradicting the previous claim.

Basically what we have done here is prove that when $f$ is totally differentiable in a point, then it is continuous in that point, and use the fact that $f$ is not continuous in $0$. Sadly I don't see another way to do this.

Comment: Very informative. thanks for the help, and yes I agree I don't think there is any other way to prove this without using the discontiuinty of $f$ at $0$

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not continuous at zero (e.g. approach the origin on the diagonal). Therefore it can't be differentiable there.